# How windows photo gallery prints images?

Tags: winapi, printing

I have to figure out how windows photo gallery (for example and likewise software) prints images. 
For doing that i traced **winapi** calls using winapi tracer and got the following result:

```
photowiz.dll    CreateDCW ( "WINSPOOL", "Microsoft XPS Document Writer", NULL, 0x000000000693bfd0 )    -> 0xffffffffd1210203        0.0377993

photowiz.dll    StartDocW ( 0xffffffffd1210203, 0x000000000355f220 ) ->     5        4.2646007

// tons of GDI/GDI+ calls but not using DC 0xffffffffd1210203

photowiz.dll    StartPage ( 0xffffffffd1210203 )    1        0.0022461

// tons of GDI/GDI+ calls but not using DC 0xffffffffd1210203

photowiz.dll    EndPage ( 0xffffffffd1210203 )    1        0.4128114

// tons of GDI/GDI+ calls but not using DC 0xffffffffd1210203

photowiz.dll    EndDoc ( 0xffffffffd1210203 )    1        1.3858542
```

So don't understand how image occurs in DC used for StartDoc/EndDoc and so on? all versions of Blits don't get this DC as parameter. What happens?

Comment: `StartDoc` have pointer to file which need print, in `DOCINFO`. in what question ? how internal `StartDoc` worked, open file, 'copy' it to DC ?

Comment: What's the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: it seems not, file name in StartDoc contains "fit to page".

Comment: It is possible that the photo gallery is using memory DCs and compatible DCs instead of drawing directly to the original DC. This is normal for GDI. What are you trying to figure out?